# jQuery Mobile page coming up with code on Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've written a webapp to keep track of statistics from my swimming. It works fine on my desktop and fine in the android mobile simulator, but when I try to use it on my Samsung Galaxy S2 using the Android browser it just shows a bunch of code. This happens right after I log in. As far as I can tell, the next page is not getting loaded.

The code for the login page (not sure if it's relevant) is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="header">

            <h1>Home</h1>

        </div>
        <div data-role="content">


<form action="" method="post">
    <div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='ILxbxRYRNmNwIzUKASEtTbhGG9gtorZf' /></div>
    <table>
        <tr><th><label for="id_username">Username:</label></th><td><input id="id_username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_password">Password:</label></th><td><input id="id_password" type="password" name="password" maxlength="4096" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/swimming/" />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>

        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">

            <a href="/swimming/session/list" data-role="button">Session List</a>
            <a href="/swimming/accounts/logout/" data-role="button">Logout</a>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code for the target page (/swimming/) is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="header">

<h1>Home</h1>

        </div>
        <div data-role="content">


        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">

            <a href="/swimming/session/list" data-role="button">Session List</a>
            <a href="/swimming/accounts/logout/" data-role="button">Logout</a>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code it spits is:

```
").append(d);return function(a){if(!(a in b)){var h=document.createElement("style"),g="@media "+a+" { #jquery-mediatest { position:absolute; } }";h.type="text/css";h.styleSheet?h.styleSheet.cssText=g:h.appendChild(document.createTextNode(g));e.prepend(f).prepend(h);b[a]=d.css("position")==="absolute";f.add(h).remove()}return b[a]}}()})(jQuery);(function(a,e){function b(a){var b=a.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+a.substr(1),a=(a+" "+c.join(b+" ")+b).split(" "),d;for(d in a)if(f[a[d]]!==e)return true}var d=a("
```

I apologize if I've been vague in my description, I'm fairly new to mobile web pages and may have missed a detail.

Comment: Your html markup should be wrapped in `data-role=page`. Use latest version 1.4, you're using an old version.

Comment: That did it, make it an answer and you've got an accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you're using a *Multi-page model* or a *Single page model*, all elements should be wrapped in `<div data-role="page></div>`.

Page div acts like `body` tag for each page. jQuery Mobile looks for *page* to create it and enhance its' elements.

Side note: I recommended using latest jQuery Mobile version **1.4**.